# array keys encoded when using http_build_query()

Tags: php, url, parameters, character-encoding

Encoding an array to a URL using `http_build_query()` produces strange behaviour when an array key is also a html-char code.

For example:

```
return http_build_query([
   'id' = > ['my', 'data', 'here'], // no problem
   'class' = > ['my', 'data', 'here'], // no problem
   'yen' = > ['my', 'data', 'here'], // ¥ html car is &yen;
   'parameter' = > ['my', 'data', 'here'], // ¶ html char is &para;
]);
```

and the encoded result is:

`id[0]=my&id[1]=data&id[2]=here&class[0]=my&class[1]=data&class[2]=here¥[0]=my¥[1]=data¥[2]=here¶meter[0]=my¶meter[1]=data¶meter[2]=here`

whats going on here, it cant be possible that i cannot use the word parameter as an array key.

Comment: its what you see in your browser, check out the `view source`

Comment: I don't understand how your code could produce such output. Please post **actual code**

Comment: yeah... Ghost is correct. I feel pretty silly...

Comment: when you want to debug in a browser, always make sure to `htmlspecialchars()` your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the source of HTML output, you will see

> id%5B0%5D=my&id%5B1%5D=data&id%5B2%5D=here&class%5B0%5D=my&class%5B1%5D=data&class%5B2%5D=here&yen%5B0%5D=my&yen%5B1%5D=data&yen%5B2%5D=here&parameter%5B0%5D=my&parameter%5B1%5D=data&parameter%5B2%5D=here

Which is correct. While displaying only, the browser will interpret malformed entities like `&yen` as ¥. There is nothing to worry about on the server side.

HTML entities [reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

**Demo:** [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/1dd2ql)

Comment: No, no. Don't. Sometimes this causes other issues. It was a valid question. For example, we wouldn't expect &parameter to be interpreted as &para; which is ¶. Browser being overly helpful.